# Using Policy Keys in Azure B2C custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing a custom policy for Azure B2C. A part of this policy is to use a custom claims provider to get some information from an Azure function and put it in the token. When calling this function a code is required to be put in as a query parameter on the call.

My policy works fine however I don't want to hard code that key or even the URL for the azure function. Is there anyway to set this URL/key as a policy key and refer to it within the policy. This way I won't need to maintain separate policies for each environment.

The metadata section of the claimsprovider in question.

```
<Metadata>
                    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://azurefuntiongoeashere/api/functionname?code=keygoeshere</Item>
                    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you secure your REST API with a conventional method like certificate/basic auth, or OAUTH, you can use a policy key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api

Comment: I feel like certificate auth is a little overkill for the data my REST API is providing. I would like to do basic auth but there doesn't seem to be a way to do basic auth with an Azure function app.

Comment: The easiest option is Oauth, protect it with Azure AD.

Comment: I want to call MS api to get token using client credentials flow.
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
How can pass client secret without hardcoding ?